# My materials texture stays purple. Why?

Tags: materials

[image]
I am following the beginners donut tutorial where Andrew adds condensation to a cup. I did everything as explained, but the purple texture appears. How can I properly make the texture work?

Comment: You are using the node wrangler add-on to preview that texture, that's way you see it.

Comment: you need to plug the Image Texture into a Vector > Normal Map node and plug this Normal Map into the Normal input of the Principled BSDF

Comment: okay it worked.